# Using .Popen() and .shlex() to load files to deluge-console

Tags: python, subprocess, shlex, deluge

I am having trouble getting a script to load files via deluge-console using .Popen() and .shlex(). I am using xubuntu and byobu on gnome-terminal.

`def torrentLoad(url):
    #client_run = subprocess.Popen(['deluged']])
    sourceList = torrentWrite(sortXML(url))
    print(sourceList)
    for s in sourceList:
        sleep(2)
        delugeList = ['deluge-console', 'add', s]
        load = subprocess.Popen(delugeList, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = load.communicate()
        print(out, err)`
The variable sourceList contains functions that parse xml and returns a list of torrent files locations. (e.g. '/home/YOURHOME/Documents/torrents/file.torrent')

In theory this should feed the command: 
deluge-console add /home/YOURHOME/Documents/torrents/file.torrent
directly to terminal. Mind you I am running Byobu as well. I don't know if that would play a part in this or not.

The output I am getting is nodda. Zilch.Thanks for any help.

Comment: first you shouldn't use `shlex.split`, just pass arguments as list `['deluge-console','add',s]`, then get stdout/stderr from `out,err = load.communicate()` so you can print errors if there are some

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in a good direction. I modified as suggested and had nothing from stdout or stderr. Still got nothing.

Comment: also add `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` as subprocess parameters

Comment: I edited to show the state of the current function. Still have not gotten any errors printed to terminal.